# Remove some html tags from the_content

Tags: wordpress

How can i output the_content with the following settings?

Allowed tags:

```
    <br />, <p>
```

Don't allow:

```
    <div> <p style""> <span> <font>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) together with [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter:

```
if( !is_admin() ) // not admin side
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'so_26068464' );

function so_26068464( $content )
{
    return strip_tags( $content, '<p><br>' );
}
```

There's [an example at PHP's manual](https://www.php.net/strip_tags#86964) on how to remove the tag ***contents*** too, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Ok that helped a bit, but your code allows <p style""> as well. I dont want that :(

Comment: nevermind, i used your code + another code that clears styling and it worked. Thanks